# Nest/Stack div elements in a timeline

Tags: html, css

**Updated question:**

I want to display events in a timeline like shown in the following image:

[image: wanted result]

The event data items have two attributes: "start time" and "length", so that the data could be imagined as a table that looks like that:

```
event name | start | length
-----------+-------+-------
1          |   0   | 200 
1.1        |  30   | 100 
1.1.1      |  40   |  50 
1.2        | 140   |  50 
2          | 205   | 100 
2.1        | 220   |  20 
2.2        | 250   |  20 
2.3        | 280   |  20 
...        | ...   | ...
```

The data has some characteristics:

- Event names can be arbitrary (here the numbers are just for purpose of illustration)
- Events that start and end within the bounds of another event are child events of those.
   → In the table above "1.1" would be a child event of "1".
- Children can have child events.
- Events do never overlap in the following way…

  ```
  +---------+                 +---------+
  |    A    |                 |    C    |
  +---------+                 +---------+
      +---------+   or   +---------+ 
      |    B    |        |    D    | 
      +---------+        +---------+
  ```

  …because B would be the child of A, but it must end before A ends. C starts within D, so that D would be the parent of C (and must be displayed above C), but then there is the same problem as with A and B.
- No explicit nesting information is available, but implicit nesting information is provided by the start time and length.
- The events are sorted ascending by start time.

So there is exactly one way how the events should be displayed.

---

Currently I'm trying do do it this way: The x-position is set with `margin-left`, but any other attribute would be fine, too. The `div`s are ordered by their x values:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item" style="margin-left:0; width: 200px;">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="margin-left:30px; width: 100px;">
        1.1
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="margin-left:40px; width: 50px;">
        1.1.1
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="margin-left:140px; width: 50px;">
        1.2
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="margin-left:205px; width: 100px;">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="margin-left:220px; width: 20px;">
        2.1
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="margin-left:250px; width: 20px;">
        2.2
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="margin-left:280px; width: 20px;">
        2.3
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
    padding: 0.5rem 0 1.5rem 0;
    background-color: #EEE;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.item {
    height: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: -1rem;
    font-size: 60%; font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #BBB;
    border: 1pt solid #EEE;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This is the current result (in this case the event names are numbers, but they can be arbitrary strings):

[image: result]

There is exactly one `div` per line, so that each subsequent `div` is below its predecessor.

Any ideas how to do this with pure CSS without having to calculate the y position of the elements?

The example code is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/hiddenbit/PvBjt/

Comment: Since you have "no information available about the y position / the level of the divs", what information do you have? Do you know _anything_ about the structure or relationship between events? I cannot think of _any_ way to infer a vertical position from only horizontal data.

Comment: There is exactly one way the timeline events have to be displayed. I added some more information to my question. (I know all might be a bit confusing ;-) )

Comment: How are you generating the current CSS? Is there anything that exists at the time the HTML is being generated we can use to give the HTML some structure. If there is no other information I'm probably going to go with a "no, not possible with pure CSS".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

You need to Be Specific and Make this relevant.

Your question has evolved from "Line up my DIV's like this picture" to "Position elements based on Unknown logic". You've self-admittedly made your question more vague with your edits rather than more clear.

Comment: @andyb: The HTML with the inline CSS is created from database data that can be imagined as 3-column table: `[text content|start|length]`. No other information is available. Maybe it is not possible with pure CSS, so that the y position must be calculated manually.

Comment: @AndrewClody: You are right, I will revise my question.

Comment: What is the server-side technology used to get the data out of the database? Also, can you add the example data that matches the image please? It's difficult to line up 3 different examples - the image with 1.1, 1.1.1, etc..., the example with foo/bar/baz and the example with ABCD!

Comment: @andyb: The solution should be independent of server technology. But after much investigation I think it is not possible with just using HTML/CSS. Probably the easiest solution is to calculate the y-positions with JavaScript, which is not too complicated.

Comment: There has to be some code that is looping through the "rows", so can't you make that loop more intelligent and give structure the events into containers?

Comment: @hiddenbit I feel like the confusion is getting and organizing data vs applying a style to your output and in this case, the two "sub-solutions" are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems not to be possible to layout the `div`s just using CSS. Therefore I made the following solution using JavaScript.

The data list gets traversed and the `div`s are added dynamically. Absolute positioning is used:

- `left` is set to the start time
- for `top` a stack data structure is used to keep track of the implicit parents

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```javascript
var data = [
    ["1",      0, 200 ],
    ["1.1",   30, 100 ],
    ["1.1.1", 40,  50 ],
    ["1.2",  140,  50 ],
    ["2",    205, 100 ],
    ["2.1",  220,  20 ],
    ["2.2",  250,  20 ],
    ["2.3",  280,  20 ]
];

var endStack = [];
var maxStackHeight = 0;
var container = document.getElementById("container");

data.forEach(function(row) {
    // create div
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "item";
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(row[0]));
    var x = row[1]; var w = row[2];
    div.style.left = x.toString() + "px";
    div.style.width = w.toString() + "px";

    // get level of div
    for (var i = endStack.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (x > endStack[i]) {  
            // current event starts after current top-of-stack ends → remove
            endStack.pop();  
        } else {
            // current event is child of current top-of-stack event
            break;
        }
    }

    // set y position based on stack height
    div.style.top = (endStack.length).toString() + "rem";

    // append to container
    container.appendChild(div);

    // push end of added event to stack
    endStack.push(x + w);

    // set maximum stack height 
    maxStackHeight = Math.max(maxStackHeight, endStack.length);
});

// set container height based on maximum stack height 
container.style.height = (maxStackHeight + 1.1).toString() + "rem";
```

**CSS:**

```css
#container {
    background-color: #EEE;
    border: 0.1rem solid #888;
    overflow-x: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.item {
    position: absolute;
    height: 2rem;
    font-size: 60%; font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #BBB;
    border: 0.1rem solid #EEE;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hiddenbit/PvBjt/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the vertical offset with negative top margins on each element.

http://jsfiddle.net/PvBjt/1/

```
margin-top:-##px;
```

Comment: I should have noted, that I have *no* level information by default. Of course this could be calculated with JavaScript, but I wonder if it is possible with pure CSS.

Comment: Yes and no :-) The result looks like the one I want, but there is no information available how the `div`s must be nested, therefore some additional processing is needed for this solution. And because the elements should be positioned with an absolute x values they must be converted to values relative to their parent.

Comment: This comment is extremely vague. You seem to have no actual design specification.

Comment: I updated my question for some more information. Put simply, there are events that start at some time and have some length. The event data does not contain explicit nesting information, but it is guaranteed that child events start and end inside the bounds of their (implicit) parents.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your `.item` to `position: absolute;` and given the sub item's classes and also a pixel `top` value:

```
.item {
  position: absolute;
}
.sub-item {
   top:35px;
}
.sub-sub-item {
  top: 55px;
}
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PvBjt/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Throwing my 2 ideas in the ring even if the requirements are *very* fuzzy.

#### First attempt

I added a `margin-top` to most elements; level `x.x` get `margin-top:20px` and level `x.x.x` get `margin-top:40px`. Similar approach to @YaMo.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WFbMx/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item" style="margin-left:0; width: 200px;">1</div>
    <div class="item" style="margin-left:30px; margin-top:20px; width: 100px;">1.1</div>
    <div class="item" style="margin-left:40px; margin-top:40px; width: 50px;">1.1.1</div>
    <div class="item" style="margin-left:140px; margin-top:20px; width: 50px;">1.2</div>
    <div class="item" style="margin-left:205px; width: 100px;">2</div>
    <div class="item" style="margin-left:220px; margin-top:20px; width: 20px;">2.1</div>
    <div class="item" style="margin-left:250px; margin-top:20px; width: 20px;">2.2</div>
    <div class="item" style="margin-left:280px; margin-top:20px; width: 20px;">2.3</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.item {
    position:absolute; /* just add to existing properties */
}
```

---

#### Second attempt

Some actual structure for the elements allows much cleaner HTML and more generic CSS. The only part I couldn't come up with a generic rule for is the width for item `1.2`. This of course depends on being able to change the HTML structure.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XDa3w/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li class="item">1
            <ul>
                <li class="item">1.1
                    <ul>
                        <li class="item">1.1.1</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="item">1.2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item">2
            <ul>
                <li class="item">2.1</li>
                <li class="item">2.2</li>
                <li class="item">2.3</li>       
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    padding: 0.5rem 0 1.5rem 0;
    background-color: #EEE;
    border: 1px solid #888;
}

.item {
    height:2rem;
    background-color: #BBB;
    border: 1pt solid #EEE;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    min-width:20px;
}

li:only-child {
    min-width:50px;
}

ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}

.container > ul > li {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    font-size: 60%; font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul li:first-child {
    margin-left:20px;
}

ul li:last-child {
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. My question was indeed too fuzzy, so I updated it. By default there is neither explicit nesting information nor y values available. Nevertheless the `div` can be positioned, because the events data is not arbitrary (→ updated question).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution using the CSS from [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16696575/637889) and JavaScript to create a structured `<ul>` of the events.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xAjna/)

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload=function(){
  var events = [
    { name: '1', start: 0, length: 300},
    { name: '1.1', start: 30, length: 100},
    { name: '1.1.1', start: 40, length: 50},
    { name: '1.2', start: 140, length: 50},
    { name: '1.3', start: 200, length: 50},
    { name: '2', start: 305, length: 100},
    { name: '2.1', start: 320, length: 20},
    { name: '2.2', start: 350, length: 20},
    { name: '2.3', start: 380, length: 20},
    { name: '3', start: 410, length: 50}
  ];

  var html = [];
  var containerEventEnd = [];
  var prevEventEnd = Infinity;

  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var e = events[i];
    var eventEnd = e.start + e.length;

    if (e.start > containerEventEnd[1]) {
      containerEventEnd.shift();
      html.push('</ul>');
    }

    if (eventEnd > containerEventEnd[0]) {
      containerEventEnd.shift();
      containerEventEnd.unshift(eventEnd);
    }

    if (e.start > prevEventEnd) {
      html.push('</li>');
    } else {
      html.push('<ul>');
      containerEventEnd.unshift(eventEnd);
    }

    html.push('<li class="item">' + e.name); // every item is just an <li>
    prevEventEnd = eventEnd;
  }

  document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = html.join('\n');
};
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    padding: 0.5rem 0 1.5rem 0;
    background-color: #EEE;
    border: 1px solid #888;
}

.item {
    height:2rem;
    background-color: #BBB;
    border: 1pt solid #EEE;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    min-width:20px;
}

li:only-child {
    min-width:50px;
}

ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}

#container > ul > li {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    font-size: 60%; font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul li:first-child {
    margin-left:20px;
}

ul li:last-child {
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: This woks, too. Depending on what is desired this would allow to change the style of parent events when one of its children is hovered ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/hiddenbit/aez7n/)). But if only the hovered event should be styled and not its parent, some extra effort is needed when using nested elements.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. It was an interesting problem to come up with solutions for :-)